# BeeByte Deobfuscation

Tags: unity-game-engine, reverse-engineering

I am a recent graduate trying to reverse engineer my way into a video game studio. I am an Alpha tester for the game and I am working on fully understanding their code from the .DLLs that have been built thus far...but some parts of it are obfuscated through a Unity utility from the Asset Store called BeeBytes. I want to get a better understanding of the networking process for games - all of their networked code is obfuscated - and I've found one way to de-obfuscate BeeBytes but I can't seem to find any sort of tutorial to configure the deobfuscator to work. I think it is a module that can be used with De4Dot and something that is run through that program.

I posted on the StackOverflow reverse-engineering forums as well and I was told to try asking here. From what I have gathered, is Beeless something you integrate into De4Dot? As I mentioned before I can't seem to find (m)any tutorials on this type of thing and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the link to the deobfuscator.
https://github.com/ioncodes/beeless

...and here's the link to De4Dot (general-purpose deobfuscator) 
https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot

Thanks a lot,
Evan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open up the vs project you can clearly see that it misses the dnlib.dll...
This is part of dnspy for example, add this dll as a reference and built it.

Comment: Thanks, will try that!